# Looking for Java Model Classes for Facebook Graph API

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, jersey, facebook-java-api, facebook-java-sdk

I do not want an SDK with Facebook specific methods because I am programming in a REST style using JAX-RS 2.0 Client (Jersey Client).

I find myself creating classes such as:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@XmlRootElement
public class User {

  public String id;
  public String name;

  public String toString () {
    return "id: " + id + "; name:" + name;
  }

}
```

Is there such a set of model classes maintained by somebody without the overhead of an SDK. I do not need a library that includes a client and custom methods for getting friends, etc. or that store credentials. I am perfectly happy with Jersey. All I need is model classes.

Any pointers? It is OK if there is an SDK that has a clean set of model classes that I could use without having to do anything with the rest of the SDK (pun unintended).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a Java wrapper for Facebook's REST Graph API (http calls to the graph api, and translations from json objects to java classes..). You can check it out on github:

https://github.com/itzikrou/fishbowl

Hope it's useful.

Comment: @kleopatra This is hardly the sort of answer that needs to be discouraged because it is a link. The question itself asks for a set of classes, which cannot be provided in the content of an SO answer, and therefore the answer can only be a link. The link is exactly to such a set of classes. Let's not throw the baby away with the bathwater. It kills the enthusiasm of a good answer and the hard work that went behind it. It is reasonable to ask somebody to include a synopsis, but when the answer is such a good fit, the least you could do is also add a kind word about the good answer.

Comment: @iRousso, ordinarily I would research your classes a bit more, but in this case I will promptly accept the answer, just to kick up the vibe a little bit, especially since you supplied the only answer! Thank you for your good work. :-) Do you get the necromancer badge? :D

Comment: @kleopatra ok, deleted. sorry but i have seen way too many instances of SO members who abuse close privileges. meta happens to be where they cluster so no point going there.